# How to change the "Index of .." template?

Tags: apache2, webserver

Hi is it possible to change this page its style, etc..?

[image: Default index of page]

---

**EDIT # 1 Nov**

With Lucio answer I got it working. I've set [IndexStyleSheet](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexstylesheet) to one specific location so it also will operate from the same file for all local domains.

```
IndexStyleSheet "http://localhost/autoindex.css"
```

But this is just one part of the answer for my question, I also wonder how I should modify the HTML. Because I want a wrapper and a menu with links to useful locations on my webserver.

[image: Default autoindex sourcecode with an added stylesheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check my project [ABBA](https://github.com/jmlemetayer/abba) which does exactly what you want. It uses [Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com) templates based on the well known [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) framework.

It is fully responsive, with multiple templates and very easy to set up.

The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jmlemetayer/abba) so you can fork it and tweak it.

It uses [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) ([GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com)) to generate distribution files.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way thanks to Gunnar Hjalmarsson!

**To change style**

Use the *IndexStyleSheet* directive. For example:

```
IndexStyleSheet "/css/style.css"
```

The `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your_site.conf` file should looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName something.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        IndexStyleSheet "/css/style.css"
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

And the `/var/www/css/style.css` stylesheet:

```
body { color: red; }
```

Result:

[image: loading]

---

Another more flexible solution..

Place an `index.html` file on the `/` directory with your own design and list directory functionality :-)

Comment: This is what I already have, but I and I'm sure many others don't like to do things like that manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to study [the mod_autoindex section](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) in the Apache documentation.

Comment: Ahh so that's how it's called! Anyway it doesn't seem to work to add "IndexStyleSheet" can you explain a little more about it?

Comment: @Fleuv: Sorry, but it was quite some time since I worked with Apache. Please study Lucio's edited answer instead.